# Confused about Winsock2.dll vs Winsock2.h?

Tags: c++, windows

I am a little confused, I am trying to make a program with no external dependencies (so it could be easily ported to UNIX for example) that has socket connection abilities. But I am unsure of what I should be using?

Is there a standard library on Windows XP, 7, 8 that can be linked against that can output a single exe that can run alone (not depend on a DLL to function)? For example on UNIX I can link against socket and use `sys/socket.h` and have like 95% of UNIX's without doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code just won't do for both. But you can use `#ifdef WIN32` to make the preprocessor consider Windows stuff only when compiling under Windows.

In the headers:

```
#ifdef WIN32
// Windows exclusive dependencies go here
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#define close(s) closesocket(s)
#else
// Linux exclusive dependencies go here
#include <sys/socket.h>
#endif
```

And inside `main()` you will need to do something like this:

```
#ifdef WIN32
WSADATA wsaData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
#endif
```

I believe this is all, the rest of the API is widely compatible with the UNIX way of using sockets.

Comment: Does `ws2_32.lib` require the `Wsock32.dll` or `WS2_32.dll` ? I want to use the least amount of "dependencies" as possible. But I don't understand why there is like 5 different DLL's with "sock" in it.

Comment: It uses `ws2_32.dll`, its part of Windows and a lighter version of `wsock32.dll`. I really can't tell the difference, I only know it's smaller and uses less memory. But you can safely replace by `wsock32.lib` if you want.